# Getting java.lang.NoSuchMethodError error while using OSGI bundle in my application

Tags: java, maven, osgi-bundle

My appliaction is using apache poi 3.12 version but I want to use Streaming formula evaluator(i.e., SXSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells) which is in 4.1.0. I can't upgrade the jar so I thought of using OSGI bundle for formula evalaution but I am getting below error :
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(Lorg/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook;)V
I am not sure whether I can use OSGI in this manner.

I have created an Activator and a service containing evaluateAllFormulas() and its implementation class and created bundle out of it. 
In my java application added above bundle for formula evaluation.

```
package tutorial.example1;

import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
import org.osgi.framework.ServiceListener;
import org.osgi.framework.ServiceRegistration;

import tutorial.example1.client.HelloServiceImpl;
import tutorial.example1.service.HelloService;

import org.osgi.framework.ServiceEvent;

public class Activator implements BundleActivator, ServiceListener
{
private ServiceRegistration registration;
    public void start(BundleContext context)
    {
        registration = context.registerService(
                HelloService.class.getName(),
                new HelloServiceImpl(),
                null);
        System.out.println("Starting to listen for service events");
        context.addServiceListener(this);
    }

    public void stop(BundleContext context)
    {
        registration.unregister();
        context.removeServiceListener(this);
        System.out.println("Stopped listening for service events.");
    }

    public void serviceChanged(ServiceEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}

package tutorial.example1.service;

import java.io.File;

public interface HelloService {
    public void evaluateAllFormula(File file);

}

package tutorial.example1.client;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFFormulaEvaluator;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import tutorial.example1.service.HelloService;
public class HelloServiceImpl implements HelloService{
    public void evaluateAllFormula(File file) {
        File tmpWorkBookFile = file;

        FileInputStream tmpWorkBookIS;
        try {
            tmpWorkBookIS = new FileInputStream(tmpWorkBookFile);
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(tmpWorkBookIS);

            SXSSFWorkbook sxssfWorkbook =new SXSSFWorkbook(workbook);
            SXSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(sxssfWorkbook);
            FileOutputStream tmpWorkBookOS = new FileOutputStream("Test234.xlsx");
            sxssfWorkbook.write(tmpWorkBookOS);
            tmpWorkBookOS.close();
            sxssfWorkbook.dispose();
            sxssfWorkbook.close();
            workbook.close();
            System.out.println("Done Formula evaluation");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
        }

    }

}

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>felix-tutorial</groupId>
    <artifactId>example-1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>

    <name>example-1</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <!-- Build Configuration -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=provided</Embed-Dependency>
                        <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>

                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${pom.groupId}.${pom.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Bundle-Name>Service listener example</Bundle-Name>
                        <Bundle-Description>A bundle that displays messages at startup
                            and
                            when service events occur</Bundle-Description>
                        <Bundle-Vendor>Apache Felix</Bundle-Vendor>
                        <Bundle-Version>1.0.0</Bundle-Version>
                        <Bundle-Activator>tutorial.example1.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
                        <Export-Package>tutorial.example1.service,
                        org.apache.poi;version="4.1.0",
                            org.apache.poi.common.*;version="4.1.0",
                            org.apache.poi.ddf.*;version="4.1.0",
                            org.apache.poi.extractor.*;version="4.1.0",
                            org.apache.poi.hpsf.*;version="4.1.0",
                            org.apache.poi.hssf.*;version="4.1.0",
                            org.apache.poi.poifs.*;version="4.1.0",
                            org.apache.poi.ss.*;version="4.1.0",
                            org.apache.poi.sl.*;version="4.1.0",
                            org.apache.poi.util.*;version="4.1.0",
                            org.apache.poi.wp.*;version="4.1.0",
                            org.apache.poi.ooxml.*;version="4.1.0",
                            org.apache.poi.openxml4j.*;version="4.1.0",
                            org.apache.poi.xddf.*;version="4.1.0",
                            org.apache.poi.xdgf.*;version="4.1.0",
                            org.apache.poi.xslf.*;version="4.1.0",
                            org.apache.poi.xssf.*;version="4.1.0",
                            org.apache.poi.xwpf.*;version="4.1.0"                           
                        </Export-Package>
                        <Import-Package>org.osgi.framework

                        </Import-Package>

                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <!-- Dependecies Management -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.felix.framework</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>

package test.test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import tutorial.example1.client.HelloServiceImpl;
import tutorial.example1.service.HelloService;

public class TestOsgiExcel {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File tmpWorkBookFile = new File("TestTemplate.xlsx");


        try {
            FileInputStream tmpWorkBookIS = new FileInputStream(tmpWorkBookFile);
            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(tmpWorkBookIS);
            tmpWorkBookIS.close();
            //Method call will be there to write to excel
            SXSSFWorkbook sxssfWorkbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(workbook);
            FileOutputStream tmpWorkBookOS = new FileOutputStream("Test234.xlsx");
            sxssfWorkbook.write(tmpWorkBookOS);
            tmpWorkBookOS.close();
            sxssfWorkbook.dispose();
            sxssfWorkbook.close();
            workbook.close();
            System.out.println("Done Streaming");
            HelloService service = new HelloServiceImpl();
            service.evaluateAllFormula(new File ("Test234.xlsx"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

I expect evaluateAllFormula() will work from OSGIBundle jar but I am getting error :

```
Done Streaming
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(Lorg/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook;)V
    at tutorial.example1.client.HelloServiceImpl.evaluateAllFormula(HelloServiceImpl.java:32)
    at test.test.TestOsgiExcel .main(TestOsgiExcel.java:34)
```

Comment: Can you remove <scope>provided</scope> from the maven dependencies and try ?

Comment: Hi @Sambit,
I tried that also but it didnt work. Thanks.

Comment: Can try to use org.apache.poi.*;version="4.1.0", in the export package section and remove other packages related to poi.

Comment: I have done almost all possible combination of poi jars. added using org.apache.poi.* as well but the same result

Comment: I have extracted the jar (i.e., example-1.jar), created from bundle. In my jar , I can see apache poi(4.1.0) package

Comment: I would suggest to write a standalone program to test before putting in OSGI bundle so that it will give you more clarity. If standalone program with Apache POI works then you can zero down to OSGI issues.

Comment: I have created a standalone application using apache-poi 4.1.0 and there my formulaEvaluation code is working fine.
But the application in which I need formual evaluation is using 3.12 and I cant upgrade the POI there. That's the reason I tried using OSGI.
 I need some way to use apache poi formulaEvlaution without upgrading the jar in main appliaction.

Comment: Why can't you upgrade ? Most Apache utilities are downward compatible.